# How to detect whether an item in deleted in this scenario

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a scenario where in a continuously running thread "timer" calls my function "custommethod". I have no control over system code this is just to demonstrate how the system works i am not even aware of what code has been written in ***system code***.

***system code***

```
   timer duration = 1000
    void timer_elapsed()
    {
          foreach(string symbol in symbols) //symbol list may vary
          {
               custommethod(symbol);
          } 
    }
```

***end system code***

so, my method "custommethod" just gets a parameter from system code periodically. The symbol list may vary when the user adds or removes the symbols which is handled by system code. what all i get is active symbols periodically. so, my concern is to keep a list of active symbols.

***my code***

```
function custommethod(string symbol)
{
      //Check whether new symbol is added or a symbol is deleted
}
```

***end my code***

This is what i have tried so far

```
    HashTable ht=new HashTable();
    function custommethod(string symbol)
    {
          //Check whether new symbol is added or a symbol is deleted
            if(!ht.ContainsKey(symbol))
            {
                ht.Add(symbol,0);  //New symbol added
            }
          //How will i come to know whether a symbol is deleted or not
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way for you to know if the timer_elapsed has occurred?

Comment: Is the timer always 1 second? If so, you could store the DateTime.Now that you enter the symbol into the HashTable and then check if it expired every time you get a new symbol.

Comment: No actually i send a message to system code using windows messaging which in turn calls custommethod function with active symbols

Comment: So you know/control when the process starts? If so, before you send the message, you can clear out the HashTable. This way you know you have the most recent list of symbols. Or am I missing something?

Comment: but i dont want the list of active symbols i want only deleted symbols. Actally i process further when a new symbol is added or a symbol is deleted

Comment: OK. So can you create a new temp HashTable when you fire off the process and populate it? Then you can do a comparison?

Answer (score 1):

If `ht` is the same `symbols` then it's bad. One should never mutate the source of a `foreach` loop.

And if that's the case you should produce a new collection, then replace it with the old one.

Comment: As i told you i have no idea about system code. This is just to simplify things.

Answer (score 1):

I would not do a "for each" method, but rather do set comparisons between the new set and old set using a HashSet (though most of this is Linq, so HashTable could be fine, IDK)

```
HashSet oldSet;//construct that correctly
HashSet newSet;//construct that correctly also
HashSet deletedSet = oldSet.Except(newSet);
HashSet addedSet = newSet.Except(oldSet);
```

Comment: I think the problem here is that the foreach is fixed. He has no way to modify that part.

Comment: @ChrisO Well then he is SOL, because if he never knows the end (bounds) of the set he can't determine the set difference.